# How to proper use forloop in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

can anyone help me with my code in ajax....i have some error in my script code in ajax because of improper use of forloop...can anyone help me with my code please.

my problem is in the ajax script code....the update.php is ok no error it works perfectly.

script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#updates').click(function (e) {

           e.preventDefault();


           var $region = $('#t_region').val();
           var $town = $('#t_town').val();
           var $uniq_id = $('#t_uniq_id').val();
           var $position = $('#t_position').val();
           var $salary_grade = $('#t_salary_grade').val();
           var $salary = $('#t_salary').val();

    for($n=1;$n<=15;$n++)   {
           var $id = $('#id'.$n).val();
           var $aic = $('#aic'.$n).val();
           var $name = $('#name'.$n).val();
           var $optA = $('#optA'.$n).val();
           var $optB = $('#optB'.$n).val();
           var $optC = $('#optC'.$n).val();
           var $optD = $('#optD'.$n).val();
           var $other_qual = $('#other_qual'.$n).val();
           var $interview = $('#interview'.$n).val();
           var $total = $('#total'.$n).val();


    }

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "update.php",
               data: {
                   region_text: $region,
                   town_text: $town,
                   uniq_id_text: $uniq_id,
                   position_text: $position,
                   salary_grade_text: $salary_grade,
                   salary_text: $salary,

              for($x=1;$x<=15;$x++) {

                   id'.$x.'_text: $id,
                   aic'.$x.'_text: $aic,
                   name'.$x.'_text: $name,
                   optA'.$x.'_text: $optA,
                   optB'.$x.'_text: $optB,
                   optC'.$x.'_text: $optC,
                   optD'.$x.'_text: $optD,
                   other_qual'.$x.'_text: $other_qual,
                   interview'.$x.'_text: $interview,
                   total'.$x.'_text: $total,
               }},
               cache: false,
               success: function (data) {


               }

           });

       });
   });
</script>
```

update.php code:

```
<?php
    include('../connection.php');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');  

    $region        = @$_POST['region_text'];
    $town          = @$_POST['town_text'];
    $uniq_id       = @$_POST['uniq_id_text'];
    $position      = @$_POST['position_text'];
    $salary_grade  = @$_POST['salary_grade_text'];
    $salary        = @$_POST['salary_text'];

$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM afnup_worksheet WHERE funiq_id = '$uniq_id'";
$duperow = mysql_query($dupesql);
if(mysql_num_rows($duperow) > 0){
    exit;
}else{

    for($n=1;$n<=15;$n++)   {


    $id           = @$_POST['id'.$n.'_text'];
    $aic          = @$_POST['aic'.$n.'_text'];
    $name         = @$_POST['name'.$n.'_text'];
    $optA         = @$_POST['optA'.$n.'_text'];
    $optB         = @$_POST['optB'.$n.'_text'];
    $optC         = @$_POST['optC'.$n.'_text'];
    $optD         = @$_POST['optD'.$n.'_text'];
    $other_qual   = @$_POST['other_qual'.$n.'_text'];
    $interview    = @$_POST['interview'.$n.'_text'];
    $total        = @$_POST['total'.$n.'_text'];



if(!empty($name)){
$query = "INSERT INTO afnup_worksheet (faic,fregion,ftown,funiq_id,fposition,fsalary_grade,fsalary,fnl_name,edu_attain,experience,seminars,eligibility,other_qual,interview,ftotal,dateinputed) 
VALUES 
('$aic','$region','$town','$uniq_id','$position','$salary_grade','$salary','$name','$optA','$optB','$optC','$optD','$other_qual','$interview','$total',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$resource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't execute code to generate an object inline, you should prepare the object before passing it to the `ajax` function if you want to use it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#updates').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        data.region_text = $('#t_region').val();
        data.town_text = $('#t_town').val();
        data.uniq_id_text = $('#t_uniq_id').val();
        data.position_text = $('#t_position').val();
        data.salary_grade_text = $('#t_salary_grade').val();
        data.salary_text = $('#t_salary').val();

        for(var $x=1;$x<=15;$x++) {
            data['id'+$x+'_text'] = $('#id'+$x).val();
            data['aic'+$x+'_text'] = $('#aic'+$x).val();
            data['name'+$x+'_text'] = $('#name'+$x).val();
            data['optA'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optA'+$x).val();
            data['optB'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optB'+$x).val();
            data['optC'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optC'+$x).val();
            data['optD'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optD'+$x).val();
            data['other_qual'+$x+'_text'] = $('#other_qual'+$x).val();
            data['interview'+$x+'_text'] = $('#interview'+$x).val();
            data['total'+$x+'_text'] = $('#total'+$x).val();
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
            // We are using response to distinguish our outer data variable here from the response
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error (look at the browser console) ?

Comment: i use dreamweaver and when i put ur code it has red line from data.region_text = $region;

Comment: Try it now, code is functional as I verified it with some dummy variables http://jsfiddle.net/q97Ny/